# Cache python3-poetry installation in circleci

Tags: python, cicd, circleci, python-poetry

I would like to cache poetry installation in `.circleci`

The command is as follows:
`curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -`
which creates a `bin` in
`/home/circleci/.local/bin/poetry`
which actually links to
`/home/circleci/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/bin/poetry` whereby `/home/circleci/.local/share/pypoetry` gets created by the installation.

After installation, doing `poetry config --list` results in

```
cache-dir = "/home/circleci/.cache/pypoetry"
experimental.system-git-client = false
installer.max-workers = null
installer.modern-installation = true
installer.no-binary = null
installer.parallel = true
virtualenvs.create = true
virtualenvs.in-project = null
virtualenvs.options.always-copy = false
virtualenvs.options.no-pip = false
virtualenvs.options.no-setuptools = false
virtualenvs.options.system-site-packages = false
virtualenvs.path = "{cache-dir}/virtualenvs"  # /home/circleci/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs
virtualenvs.prefer-active-python = false
virtualenvs.prompt = "{project_name}-py{python_version}"
warnings.export = true
```

In my config.yml I tried many variations of the following:

```yaml
      - restore_cache: # **restores saved dependency cache if the Branch key template or requirements.txt files have not changed since the previous run**
            key: deps1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "pyproject.toml" }}
            paths:
              - "/home/circleci/.cache/pypoetry"
      - run:
            name: Install poetry
            command: |
              curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -

      - save_cache: # ** special step to save dependency cache **
            key: deps1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "pyproject.toml" }}
            paths:
              - "/home/circleci/.cache/pypoetry"
```

Where in the `paths`: key I tried

```
- /home/circleci/.cache/pypoetry
- /home/circleci/.cache
- /home/circleci/.local/bin/
- /home/circleci/.local/share/pypoetry
- /home/circleci/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/bin
```

Caching in `.circleci` itself works well, for example caching the libraries installed by poetry, works flawlessly

```
      - restore_cache: # **restores saved dependency cache if the Branch key template or requirements.txt files have not changed since the previous run**
            key: deps1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "poetry.lock" }}
            paths:
              - "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs"
      - run:
            name: Install dependencies with poetry
            command: |
              poetry install

      - save_cache: # ** special step to save dependency cache **
            key: deps1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "poetry.lock" }}
            paths:
              - "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs"
```